# ffmpeg - does the position of the "-preset" option matter?

Tags: ffmpeg

Does it matter where in the order of arguments I place the -preset option? Ex:

```
ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -c:v libx264 -b:v 1.5M -c:a aac -b:a 128k -preset fast target.mp4
```

vs.

```
ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -preset fast -c:v libx264 -b:v 1.5M -c:a aac -b:a 128k target.mp4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference with your two commands. You are not using any additional options that conflict with `-preset`.

- General option placement does matter. Anything before `-i` gets applied to the input. Anything after `-i` gets applied to the output. The [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) will tell you what options are for the input or the output only.
- Order of output options can matter. The option listed last generally takes precedence. For example, the `-map` option can take advantage of placement order to select certain streams. Using `-map 0 -map -0:a` would select all streams from input 0, but then deselect all audio streams from input 0.